# How do I make a variable equal the system time and now keep changing to the system time

Tags: java, time

Hi how do I make `int x = (Sys.getTime() * 1000) / Sys.getTimerResolution();` equal the system time without `x` constantly changing to the system time after that. For example if I write a piece of code that waits for `100 milliseconds` to do something `(x + 100)`, `x` will always be `100` above the system time. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a value to a variable, that value doesn't change unless you assign a new value to the variable. Therefore, if you assign a value to `x` once, it won't change. The value of `x` will reflect the system time at the time the assignment was made. It won't automatically update as time passes.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to keep the variable containing the desired value.

However, on this particular case, the best solution is using a function that returns that value, instead of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a thread to keep the current time variable updated.

Answer (score 0):

Well simply:

- Use the `new Date()` to get the system time.
- Get it in milliseconds.
- And then add to it your time in milliseconds.
- And finally make a new `Date(long date)` with your new time.

  `long x=new Date().getTime()+10000;
  Date dt=new Date(x);
  System.out.println(dt);`

And to update your variable, you can use a `Thread`:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    long x=new Date().getTime()+10000;
    Date dt=new Date(x);
    System.out.println(dt);
  }
};
```